# Conditional cumulative sum with apply functions in R

Tags: r, apply, cumsum

May be this question already addressed and answered in SO, but couldn't able to find out. I'm computing cumulative sum with conditions on a very large data frame. Look at the below example

```
Data=data.frame("Catg"=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","F"),"Val"=c(67,42,12,32,28,1,11,9,38,61,75,99,22,44,89,99,51,34,82,99,74,42))
Res=NULL
UniqCatg=unique(Data$Catg)
for(i in 1:length(UniqCatg))
    Res=c(Res, cumsum(Data[Data$Catg==UniqCatg[i],"Val"]))
Data$Res=Res
Data
```

Is there a smart way to do it without for loops? (like apply functions)

Comment: Hi, I notice you have ***never*** accepted an answer. You might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of SO. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with `plyr::ddply`...

```
require( plyr )
ddply( Data , "Catg" , transform , Res = cumsum(Val) )
#   Catg Val Res
#1     A  67  67
#2     A  42 109
#3     A  12 121
#4     A  32 153
#5     A  28 181
#6     B   1   1
#7     B  11  12
#8     B   9  21
#9     C  38  38
#10    C  61  99
#11    C  75 174
#12    D  99  99
#13    D  22 121
#14    D  44 165
#15    D  89 254
#16    D  99 353
#17    D  51 404
#18    D  34 438
#19    D  82 520
#20    E  99  99
#21    E  74 173
#22    F  42  42
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ave`:

```
Data$Res <- ave(Data$Val, Data$Catg, FUN=cumsum)
#   Catg Val Res
#1     A  67  67
#2     A  42 109
#3     A  12 121
#4     A  32 153
#5     A  28 181
#6     B   1   1
#7     B  11  12
#8     B   9  21
#9     C  38  38
#10    C  61  99
#11    C  75 174
#12    D  99  99
#13    D  22 121
#14    D  44 165
#15    D  89 254
#16    D  99 353
#17    D  51 404
#18    D  34 438
#19    D  82 520
#20    E  99  99
#21    E  74 173
#22    F  42  42
```

Comment: +1 - I wanted to post this, but if you don't type `FUN` you get an error and I could not for the life of me work out why this wasn't working for me... until you posted it. Due to the `...` for grouping variables I guess